# Can't download MySql in windows 10

Tags: mysql

I can't install MySql, every it shows that "MySql didn't find packages in the current bundle suitable for installation

[MySql-download problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYWYo.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Web community edition, try with the offline version and install it. In case of issue persist after download disconnect your internet. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the previously installed versions. I had some kind of network problem so when I installed it for the first time, the installation wasn't complete. And I tried to install it again.